# Symfony3 Multi database / sites-enabled environment

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony

I am building a multi db application that requires to choose the db, based on user that has logged in.

So there would be a shared table for settings and FOS user bundle configuration, but rest of the tables would be allocated in different databases, based on a group that user has been added to.

I have managed to find tutorials how to use different connections based on subdomains, but this doesn't apply in my case.

How can this be archived?

Comment: Are the database schemas different or are these just multiple databases having the same tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have to define your connections as described here: [How to Work with multiple Entity Managers and Connections](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html).

And then you could create a service returning you the appropriate entity manager based on the user group.

The service definition:

```
app.user_database_helper:
    class: AppBundle\UserDatabaseHelper
    arguments:
      - "@security.token_storage"
      - "@doctrine"
```

The service class:

```
namespace AppBundle;

use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorage;

class UserDatabaseHelper
{
    private $tokenStorage;
    private $doctrine;

    public function __construct(TokenStorage $tokenStorage, Registry $doctrine)
    {
        $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
        $this->doctrine = $doctrine;
    }

    public function getManager()
    {
        $token = $this->tokenStorage->getToken();
        if (!$token) {
            // return an entity manager for unauthenticated users
            return $this->doctrine->getManager('unauthenticated');
        }

        $user = $token->getUser();

        // set the manager name based on the user data
        $managerName = ...;

        return $this->doctrine->getManager($managerName);
    }
}
```

Within your controller you can just get the entity manager using:

```php
$manager = $this->get('app.user_database_helper')->getManager();
```

Comment: That is a great idea. Thanks a lot!